# When do I add hair to my model?

Tags: particles, workflow, hair

I have sculpted a humanoid Rat and have retopologized it. As many of the youtube tutorials say, I am supposed to proceed to UV unwrapping. I want to add hair to my character (fur to be specific) and it will be an animated character (I will rig and get it animated from Mixamo).

Now what should I do? Should I add hair particle system before uv unwrapping to the retopoed mesh or after it?

Comment: it would be more logical to give hair to the low-poly version, the one you'll use

Answer (score 0):

You can do UV unwrapping and hair particles independently of each other.

UV unwrapping creates UV maps. You can find them in the `Object Data Properties`.

`Hair particles` create particle settings and adds a hair modifier to the object.

As long as you haven't started to paint textures or edit/comb the hair you can delete uv maps and particle settings and re-create them.